# See errors on developer facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a lot of error on my facebook app.

Where i could see it on developer facebook ?

[image]

Comment: You should do your own logging in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a try-catch printing the obtained Exception.